# Clojure result returned is always function rather then result

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

So I'm having trouble in that every time I evaluate a Clojure function, or type in in a REPL and call it, I'm not getting the result but something like `#function[clojure.core/map/fn--5880]`.

What's causing this issue? I should be getting a result like a list here but I'm not. If I were to define everything in the REPL and run it, the result shows up just fine.

It mostly doesn't matter what I put in, Anything marginally advanced will cause this.

More specifics:

Upon request.

```clj
    (def filename "tester.csv")
    
    (defn parse
      "Convert a CSV into rows of columns"
      [string]
      (map #(clojure.string/split % #"\n")))
```

In REPL:

```clj
    (parse (slurp filename))
```

Comment: "It mostly doesn't matter what I put in, Anything marginally advanced will cause this" I have been programming Clojure off and on for almost 5 years, and I have never had  the problem you describe, even when doing complex data processing. It may seem like a very obvious problem to you, but that does not mean it is necessarily obvious to someone else. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 5):

In this specific case, you got `function[clojure.core/map/fn--5880]` and we can deduce from the name that this is a helper function defined in `clojure.core/map`. This is a transducer, which is returned when `map` is invoked only with one parameter. If you want a collection, give `map` a function and (at least) one collection.

Comment: Specifically you can for example split the input on newlines, and then map over the list of strings and split on comma: `(defn parse "Convert a CSV into rows of columns" [strings] (map #(clojure.string/split % #",") (clojure.string/split strings #"\n")))`. Example: `(parse "foo,bar\nquz,zuz") ;; => (["foo" "bar"] ["quz" "zuz"])`

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
(defn parse
  "Convert a CSV into rows of columns"
  [string]
  (clojure.string/split string #"\n"))

(parse (slurp "tester.csv"))
```

But csv you need to parse, because the delimiter can be part of the content of each cell (e.g. within quotation marks).

For that look at https://github.com/clojure/data.csv .

There in the Readme, you can see:

```
;; CLI/deps.edn dependency information:
;; so you add this into your `deps.edn`

org.clojure/data.csv {:mvn/version "1.0.1"}

;; Leiningen dependency information
;; and this you need into your project dependencies:

    [org.clojure/data.csv "1.0.1"]

;; Maven dependency information:
;; and this would be the maven dependency information,
;; if you would need it:

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
      <artifactId>data.csv</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

;; and this is how you use it:

(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv]
         '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(with-open [reader (io/reader "in-file.csv")]
  (doall
    (csv/read-csv reader)))

(with-open [writer (io/writer "out-file.csv")]
  (csv/write-csv writer
                 [["abc" "def"]
                  ["ghi" "jkl"]]))
```